# computing points by determine the neighbors algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I am doing a coding challenge in c++ regarding checking the values of a vector.
I have been stuck on this challenge for hours and I can't think of a proper solution.
I have a vector which is called values that looks like this :

```
std::vector <char > values {a,b,a,b,b,b,a,a,a,a,b,b,a};
```

Then after three values a column is started , so at the end this is how the values should be looked at:

```
abaaa
bbab 
abab
```

Player 1 has the letter a and player 2 the letter b. If player one has orthogonally connecting a's (exluding diagonal a's) he get's points.If one a is not connected to any other a player 1 get's one point. Two a's are worth 2 points and for 3 a's 5 points. Always excluding diagonal a's.If there are more than 3 connected a's player 1 gets 2 points extra. for example 4 a's 7 points and 5 a's are 9 points.This applies for player 2 as well.The tricky part is that a player can get points for more than one group of orthogonally connects a's or b's.So for example if player 1 has a group of 3 a's he gets 5 points. If he also has a single a he get's a point.So at the end he get's 6 points altogether.

```
abaaa 
bbab 
abab
```

Player 1 gets : 9+1+1

Player 2 gets: 7+2

I hope my question is clear.
I would be thankful for any hint or algorithm I could use.

I really don't know how to start.

Comment: Sounds like a [flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) is needed

Comment: or maybe a depth first search algorithm. Can't think of any other algorithm at the moment.

Comment: I hadn't heard about flood fill algorithms before, but a similar approach would be to find all connected components. We have an edge from a node to any of its four cardinal neighbors iff the cardinal neighbors have an equivalent value to that node. After processing, we just need to compute the size of each connected component and the associated value and add the calculated score to the corresponding player. It might help to re-format the input string as a 2-D grid first, although it is possible to traverse the original string as a graph if you're clever.

Comment: @john I checked implementations of flood fill algorithm and they use a multidimensional vector. Would it also work for 1d vector ?

Comment: @konoha Unless I've misunderstood then *conceptually* you have 2D structure, even if you are actaully holding it in a 1D vector. So as long as you can work out in your 1D vector where the up, down, left and right adjacent locations are (and where the edges are) you can perform a flood fill operation. (e.g. a move to the left is done by adding 3 to the current index).

Comment: Could you provide a link to the coding challenge, please? Are they giving you the data as a 1d array? There's not much to work from here, unfortunately.

Comment: @ggorlen unfortunately I don't have the link to the challenge. It dosen't have to be a 1d array but I thought it would be easier to do it with a 1d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) is an N-dimensional array region filling algorithm. It's used by e.g. bucket fill tools in image editing software to fill regions of similar color with a new color. It can be implemented with just about any graph search algorithm (DFS, BFS, etc.). It is also very similar to the types of array searching algorithms used in e.g. video games to find shortest paths between AI and their targets (except that in flood fill you don't have to number the tokens as they are traversed with their distances from the origin to compute an actual path).

The basic premise is:

1. Set a token counter to zero. Choose a token which has not yet been "filled" (perhaps keep track of a boolean "filled" flag for each token in the vector), and record its character.
2. Mark the token as "filled" and increment the token counter.
3. Search in all orthogonal directions adjacent to the token (at most four, in this case; fewer than four if you're at an "edge" of the 2D array). For each of these adjacent tokens, if they have **not** already been filled, and if they **are** the same character as the current character in question (recorded in step 1), then recurse on them starting from step 2 (or just push them into a stack / queue and iterate, as is traditional in DFS / BFS respectively). You can also do this conditional check at the start of the recursive function rather than just before calling the recursive function, as Wikipedia's example does. If recursing, make sure to provide the recursive calls with (non-constant) references to the token counter so that all recursive calls increment the same token counter.
4. Once all recursive calls have completed, it means the search branching off of the token selected in step 1 has completed. The value stored in the token counter, at this point, represents the number of tokens which were orthogonally connected to the token chosen in step 1. All of those connected tokens have now been marked as "filled". Determine the "score" associated with the value in the token counter, and add it to the correct player's score (depending on the character recorded in step 1).
5. Repeat from step 1 until all tokens are marked as "filled".

The cited Wikipedia page also provides pseudocode for the recursive function.

Of course, you have been given a 1D array (vector) rather than 2D. That being said, you can translate 2D movements into 1D movements with some basic conditional logic. For instance, you might traverse "rightward" one unit along the theoretical 2D array by simply traversing forward three units along the 1D array (given that there are 3 elements in a column). The rest of this logic can be left as an exercise for the reader (be careful around the array "edges").

Alternatively, you can convert the 1D array into a 2D array by simply "reshaping" it, leaving "tombstones" (placeholders) in the the empty spaces of the last column if necessary. Mark tombstones as "filled" by default so that they are never traversed.